# How to determine if a string can generate another string

Tags: string

How can i  Develop an application that analyzes and tells the user if a string (A) can GENERATE to another chain (B), for example

Check-in:
Chain A: "I love to program in Java"
Chain B: "Jam"

Check out:
Yes! The string "I love programming in Java" can generate the string "Jam".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: You might want to explain what you mean by GENERATE? What is the process where a string generates another string?

Comment: like if the letters contained in the first string can be taken to create the second string. both are written by the user. Example hello world has the same characters as hollow so Hello world can generate hollow.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use stl functions, i.e. use std::string::find() in Chain A for each letter from Chain B.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/